# How to stop to close the JDialog when esc key is press

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

how i can stop JDialog to close to close when the Esc key is press. i want keep it as it is.
i have already tried the dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); but this is not working on Esc key

Answer (score 2):

I was not aware that the escape key would close a dialog automatically. At least it doesn't work using JDK7 on Windows 7.

If it does work on other Look and Feels, then I would guess that LAF is using Key Bindings.

You could try to use a dummy key binding:

```
KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false);
InputMap im = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(escapeKeyStroke, "do nothing");
```

If that doesn't help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @user3363563, and yet you have NOT posted a `SSCCE`. Nor have you stated what OS version of Java you are using. I'm not a mind reader to I can't offer any more help. Good luck.